# ffmpeg decoding m4a to strange values, +/- 2.93864e38, zeros, nan, etc

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, codec, aac, m4a

i'm using pre-compiled binaries for ffmpeg, and it's decoding m4a AAC to strange values, thus it sounds a bit noisy, would expect values between -1 and 1

upper lower limits: +/- 2.93864e38
NAN
zeros

Comment: Audio is clipped between 1 and -1 floats, and sounds 'ok', but something is up with the decode

Comment: Not sure what the Q is. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, verify the issue by encoding a known waveform (sine/square-wave) and then decode and check.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya.  The issue is solved.  It was a decode loop increment error....